# Cutting glasses cloths out of old clothing

Tags: clothing, eyeglasses, fabric

I have old clothes lying around, many of which don't fit me or are too damaged to be worn outside the house.  I also keep losing my glasses cloths a lot.  So, why not cut up old T-shirts or similar into little squares so I don't have to keep buying cloths?

**So, if I want to cut up an old article of clothing and use the pieces as glasses cloths, what should said clothing be made of?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very clean cotton (dust in the fabric can scratch, which is why you aren't supposed to use the t-shirt you are wearing to clean your glasses). Microfiber is what everyone recommends, but I doubt you have any clothes made of that.

Be careful with synthetic fabric, as I have heard a number of times that some types can scratch glasses (although never any specification on which types are safe and which types are not).

If you are cutting a t-shirt, it shouldn't fray, but the ends will roll. If you are cutting woven fabric, use pinking shears to slow fraying.